# Is there a simple description of this group?

Tags: gr.group-theory

I would like to know if there is a simple description of the following group. It has 2 generators whose the square of the commutator is trivial.
$$G=\langle a,b | (aba^{-1}b^{-1})^2=1\rangle$$
By advance thank you.
Edgar.

Comment: Perhaps change the title to something more descriptive?

Comment: title changed..

Comment: For future reference: "title" refers to the title of the question, not your professional title.

Comment: as $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=bab^{-1}a^{-1}$ the group is Abelian.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry It isn't abelian. In fact it's hyperbolic.

Comment: if $ab=ba$ then my condition holds? @DerekHolt

Comment: But $ab \ne ba$ in $G$.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent

Comment: I know that - I assumed $G$ *could* be abelian - does this definition mean it isn't?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: The definition describes a unique group. There is no "could" here. Either G is abelian or it isn't. Derek's claim is that it isn't (and Derek is right as can be checked with the representation of $G$ Adam P. Goucher gave in his answer)

Comment: For example, the non-Abelian group $A_{4}$ is a (proper) homomorphic image of the group $G$ ( $A_{4}$ satisfies these relations with $a = (123), b = (124)$).

Comment: I'm still a bit confused - because it was not explicitly stated $ab=ba$, we can safely assume $G$ is non-abelian?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group for a definition of the notation $\langle ... | ... \rangle$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No, we can't assume that $G$ is not abelian. It has to be proved that $G$ is not abelian. Geoff Robinson's comment provides an elementary proof of this. I probably unwittingly confused you by stating this without proof - in fact the assertions I made in my comment were the result of a quick computer calculation.

Comment: Somewhat related to Adam P. Goucher's answer: your group is a 2-generator, 1-relator group with torsion, and such a group $G=\langle a, b; R^n\rangle$, $n>1$ is Fuchsian if and only if $G\cong \langle a, b; [a, b]^n\rangle$ (see Fine and Rosenberger, *Classification of all generating pairs of two generator Fuchsian groups* (Groups St Andrews, 1993), if and only if $R$ is a cyclic shift of $[a, b]^{\pm1}$ (from the isomorphism problem for 2-generator, 1-relator groups with torsion). So your group is Fuchsian, which is essentially what the answer notes (my point is that it generalises to $n>2$).

Comment: Your group is the fundamental group of an orbifold $O$, with genus one and a single cone point of order 2. See Peter Scott's article `The geometries of 3-manifolds' for a comprehensive discussion of 2-dimensional orbifolds.  The fact that the (rational) Euler characteristic $\chi(O)=-1/2$ is negative implies that the universal cover of $O$ is the hyperbolic plane, and your group is a cocompact Fuchsian group.

Comment: PS Scott's article can be downloaded from his webpage: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~pscott/ .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Cayley graph is the skeleton of the order-4 octagonal tiling:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-4_octagonal_tiling

Consequently, we can construct your group $G$ as a (normal) subgroup of the symmetry group of this hyperbolic tiling, which is in turn is a subgroup of the symmetry group of the hyperbolic plane, which can be embedded in $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ by the Poincare disc model.

Specifically, we take $a : \mathbb{CP}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$ to be the Möbius map:

$$ z \mapsto \dfrac{(p+1)z + p}{pz + (p+1)} $$

where $p = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{2})}$. Similarly, take $b$ to be the map obtained by conjugating $a$ by a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (multiplication by $i$):

$$ z \mapsto \dfrac{(p+1)z - pi}{ipz + (p+1)} $$

These are two perpendicular translations of the Poincaré disc, and $G = \langle a , b \rangle$ is isomorphic to your group.